# OpenGL on Mac OS X in a second thread

Tags: multithreading, macos, opengl

I've been searching the internet but couldn't quite find a reliable answer to this question.

I have a program, which spins a second thread. From this second thread (which is not the main thread) it opens a GLFW window and does **all** of the OpenGL calls. No other thread does a single OpenGL call.

Is this fine on Mac OS X? Some sources suggested that OS X can only do OpenGL in a main thread, some suggest it's not the case, so I'm wondering. (I don't have a Mac to test it myself).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work because I have tried the same with my Mac. I also do not see why it should not work. Furthermore, why don't you just try it out? It should be very short to write a test code that renders a triangle or something. Just be careful about race conditions, as always when dealing with multithreading.

Actually, new Graphics APIs rely on exact this *vulnerability* because while OpenGL will block your main thread, the other can do processing of data, which gives you some shorter net time per frame.

Check out https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/ . This API lives by exploiting such parallelization.

Comment: I can't try because I don't have a Mac, but I'm developing a library that should work on a Mac. Thanks for the answer, just to make sure: have you tried doing **all** of the OpenGL calls in the second non-main thread?